# Plotly.py bug using discrete colour data on stacked bar chart with customdata in hover text

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df` which I am using to populate a Plotly bar chart. For the sake of example, let's define `df` as the following:

```
import pandas, numpy
import plotly.express as px

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "x": ["John Cleese", "Eric Idle", "Michael Palin", "Eric Idle"],
        "y": [7, 10, 3, 8],
        "colour": ["0", "0", "0", "1"],
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "b": [1, 4, 9, 16],
        "c": [1, 8, 27, 64]
    }
)
```

And create a bar chart derived from these data

```
fig = px.bar(df, x="x", y="y", color="colour", barmode="stack")

my_customdata = numpy.transpose(numpy.array([df["a"], df["b"], df["c"]]))

fig = fig.update_traces(
    patch={
        "customdata": my_customdata,
        "hovertemplate": "x: %{x}, y: %{y}, a: %{customdata[0]}, b: %{customdata[1]}, c: %{customdata[2]}<extra></extra>"
    },
    overwrite=True
)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={"categoryorder": "total ascending"}
)
fig.show()
```

The bug arises in the hover text for the red stacked bar. You'll notice that the `x` and `y` data in the hover text are correct, but the data arising from the `customdata` are not!

[image: Discrete colour data causes customdata to be out of order]

Intriguingly, this error only occurs when the `Pandas.Series` object passed to the `color` argument of `px.bar()` consists of string data (i.e. discrete colour data). If in the code above I instead set `df.colour = [0, 0, 0, 1]` (using integers for continuous colour data, notice the colorbar), the following graph is created:

[image: Continuous colour data workaround]

My project requires the use of discrete colour data, is there a workaround for this bug?

Originally asked at https://community.plotly.com/t/bug-using-bar-chart-categoryorder-and-customdata/43925?fbclid=IwAR2yKnSgedDjDmIGe3vhd8GPiQ_DFFAGephrq6G4Wl80iJST3Psn6kkzIs8

and subsequently asked at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2716

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was relatively simple, and was my fault rather than being an issue with the source code itself (oh, the hubris of thinking that it wasn't my fault!)

#### The reason my code breaks

On running `px.bar()`, `plotly.express` creates a `plotly.graph_objs.Figure` object which contains *two* `Bar` objects, not one. Then, when `fig.update_traces()` is called, the `customdata` is applied to *all* of the `Bar` objects which are children of `fig`. Red Eric Idle is the 4th value of the original DataFrame, but `fig.update_traces()` doesn't care where Red Eric Idle *used* to be - it only understands that now it's part of a second `Bar` object. In fact, Red Eric Idle is the first datapoint of this `Bar` object, and so merrily assigns creates hovertext data using `customdata[0][n]`, `customdata[1][n]`, `customdata[2][n]`, with `n=0` (the first value), rather than with `n=3` (the fourth value) as I expected.

*This* is why the hover text for Red Eric Idle contains `"a: 1, b: 1, c: 1"`, rather than `"a: 4, b: 16:, c: 64"`.

#### The solution

The solution is very straightforward. Since the Plotly figure "forgets" where in the original DataFrame each point's data was supposed to go after it finishes running `px.bar()`, we simply have to assign custom data to each datapoint *before* it forgets (i.e. during the `px.bar()` call. Simply replace

```
fig = px.bar(df, x="x", y="y", color="colour", barmode="stack")
my_customdata = numpy.transpose(numpy.array([df["a"], df["b"], df["c"]]))
fig = fig.update_traces(
    patch={
        "customdata": my_customdata,
        "hovertemplate": "x: %{x}, y: %{y}, a: %{customdata[0]}, b: %{customdata[1]}, c: %{customdata[2]}<extra></extra>"
    },
    overwrite=True
)
```

with

```
fig = px.bar(
    df, x="x", y="y", color="colour", barmode="stack", custom_data=["a", "b", "c"]
)
fig = fig.update_traces(
    patch={
        "hovertemplate": "x: %{x}, y: %{y}, a: %{customdata[0]}, b: %{customdata[1]}, c: %{customdata[2]}"
    },
    overwrite=True
)
```

Hey presto, Red Eric Idle suddenly has hover text with the `4, 16, 64` rather than `1, 1, 1`:

[image: Expected hover text behaviour is restored]

This is also neater code in the first place. It wasn't obvious to me in the original Plotly example documentation that `custom_data` could be assigned like this within the `plotly.express` module.

#### Why this didn't happen for continuous colour data

But why does this strange behaviour go away when we set `df.colour = [0, 0, 0, 1]`?

The reason is that when `px.bar()` is passed continuous colour data, it only creates one `Bar` object per figure. In this case, every datapoint in `Bar` remembers its row position in the DataFrame, and so the assignment of `customdata` works like a charm.